# Convert XML to dataframe, edit, then convert back to XML in R?

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML document that has a fairly ordered stucture, (although I don't have anything as nice as a schema or a DTD).  I want to change / add / remove some fo the elements of my XML file, with input from others.

To do this I want to take my XML file, Convert it to a dataframe with one row per tag and one column per attribute, then edit the dataframe (or export to csv, have someone else edit, then pull back in), then convert back to XML.

At the moment, this code does the first part to convert XML to dataframe

```
foo<-xmlParseDoc("example.xml")

bar<-xmlSApply(xmlRoot(foo), xmlAttrs, addNamespaceURLs=TRUE)

tempdf<-data.frame()
templist<-list()
n<-1

for(i in seq(length(bar))){
    message(i)
    if(!is.null(bar[[i]])){
        message(bar[[i]])
        tempdf<-rbind.fill(tempdf, data.frame(t(bar[[i]]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
        n<-n+1
    }
}
```

but I'm stuck on how to convert this dataframe back to the XML equivalent.  Any ideas ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `dataFrameToXml` function because there is no unique chunk of XML that could be generated.  Take a look at the help page for `xmlTree` to see if it gets you started.

Answer (score -2):

How about the xmlToDataFrame package? I would assume it has methods not only for reading xml to a frame, but also writing a frame back into an XML file. Never used it myself though

Comment: Where can I find the `xmlToDataFrame` package?  It isn't on CRAN.  There's an `xmlToDataFrame` function in the `XML` package.  Is that what you mean?